# How to test elements visibility into a dropdown scroll with Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, dropdown

I have a bootstrap Angular dropdown, when you click on it, it makes visible an UL element which has overflow-y set to auto and therefore some of the items inside are not visible, only after scrolling up or down.

I implemented a method to scroll automatically to the selected element (default behavior is to remember last scroll position) so I would like to test it with Protractor.

I've already tried with isDisplayed() method, turning it to be true for all elements within this UL (although only 10 out of 20 are actually visible)

```
expect(item20.isDisplayed()).toBe(false); //returns true
```

After that I tried to click on them, expecting to throw error "element not visible" but all of them were successfully clicked.

Any ideas about how to test if an item is in the visible part of this scroll?

[image: Visible elements]

Comment: Quick check: do you see the test failing in both Firefox and Chrome? Trying to rule out a browser-specific problem..

Comment: Results are the same for all browsers, the problem is with isDisplayed, to Protractor these elements inside the scroll are all visible.

Comment: Okay, could you post the complete HTML representation of the dropdown? Wonder, why selenium thinks the elements are visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that for Protractor these items are actually visible so isDisplayed will return true for all of them.

So I used getLocation() method to compare initial and final positions of the scrolled elements and therefore checking they were properly located.

```
expect(selectedElement.getLocation()).toEqual(selectedElementInitialLocation);
```